# USBError: [Errno 2] Entity not found in Python 2.6

Tags: python, usb

I am trying to list my usb devices with python 2.6.6 on Windows 7 64-bit. this is the script I am using:

```
import usb

def list_devices(idVendor=None, idProduct=None):
    """Look through the usb tree for devices with a given Vendor ID and, if
       specified, a Product ID. Return list of usb.Device classes.
    """
    return_devices=[]
    busses=usb.busses()

    for bus in busses:
        for device in bus.devices:
            if device.idVendor == idVendor or idVendor==None:
                if device.idProduct == idProduct or idProduct == None:
                    print("Vendor id: "+str(hex(device.idVendor))+" Product id: "+str(hex(device.idProduct))+"\n")
                    return_devices.append(device)

    return return_devices

if __name__=="__main__":
    list_devices()
```

This is the error message that I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/Scripts/find_usb_devices", line 25, in <module>
    list_devices()
  File "C:/Python26/Scripts/find_usb_devices", line 13, in list_devices
    busses=usb.busses()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\usb\legacy.py", line 333, in busses
    return (Bus(),)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\usb\legacy.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.devices = [Device(d) for d in core.find(find_all=True)]
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\usb\legacy.py", line 314, in __init__
    self.configurations = [Configuration(c) for c in dev]
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 723, in __iter__
    yield Configuration(self, i)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 419, in __init__
    configuration
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb10.py", line 471, in get_configuration_descriptor
    config, byref(cfg)))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb10.py", line 403, in _check
    raise USBError(_str_error[ret], ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
USBError: [Errno 2] Entity not found
```

It would be convenient if someone can help to resolve this issue. The strange thing is that when I try the same code on Python 2.7 on my laptop running Windows 10, it runs smoothly. Thank you in advance.